# Is is possible to create a grouped bar chart in HighChartJS?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Basically I want same grouped column chart(in the JS fiddle) to be displayed as a grouped bar chart, and I think setting the chart type to 'bar' does not do the trick.
Is it not possible to have a grouped bar chart, or am I missing some other configuration options that need to be changed?

[JS Fiddle Link Here](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/column-grouping-false/)

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Monthly Average Rainfall'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: [
            'Jan',
            'Feb',
            'Mar',
            'Apr',
            'May',
            'Jun',
            'Jul',
            'Aug',
            'Sep',
            'Oct',
            'Nov',
            'Dec'
        ]
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Rainfall (mm)'
        }
    },
    legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
        align: 'left',
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        x: 100,
        y: 70,
        floating: true,
        shadow: true
    },
    tooltip: {
        shared: true,
        valueSuffix: ' mm'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            grouping: false,
            shadow: false
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Tokyo',
        data: [49.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],
        pointPadding: 0

    }, {
        name: 'New York',
        data: [83.6, 78.8, 98.5, 93.4, 106.0, 84.5, 105.0, 104.3, 91.2, 83.5, 106.6, 92.3],
        pointPadding: 0.1

    }, {
        name: 'London',
        data: [48.9, 38.8, 39.3, 41.4, 47.0, 48.3, 59.0, 59.6, 52.4, 65.2, 59.3, 51.2],
        pointPadding: 0.2

    }, {
        name: 'Berlin',
        data: [42.4, 33.2, 34.5, 39.7, 52.6, 75.5, 57.4, 60.4, 47.6, 39.1, 46.8, 51.1],
        pointPadding: 0.3

    }]
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that this config includes also the plotOptions for column series, you need to change it to do the same for bar series.

```
plotOptions: {
    bar: {
        grouping: false,
        shadow: false
    }
},
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/fzqr4h2u/

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.bar